Can 疲劳驾驶 be considered 成语？
Dictionary definition of成语seems very vague on what constitutes 成语。some says it has to be 4 characters, some says no
一定要在成语字典才算吗？为什么一些是四字俗语？
Side question：21世纪有新成语吗？

read this , 疲劳驾驶 is not an idiom, watch this

also read my answer here

You have asked too many questions in a single post, please narrow it down to one or two that you are most eager to know. Also, examples of 四字俗语 will help (do you mean "四字格俗语?).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chengyu

https://www.zhihu.com/question/595777955/answer/2988834013?utm_psn=1802875442874683392

上面是一个很大的关于现代成语的知乎问题，里面有很多相关回答。我认为现代已经几乎成为成语的词：《三体》降维打击、思想钢印；《火影忍者》秽土转生；《成龙历险记》岁月史书；《英雄联盟》虚空索敌；……

疲劳驾驶不算成语。成语一般用来比喻或者暗喻，而不是字面意思，比如唇亡齿寒，画蛇添足，而疲劳驾驶就是字面意思，没有其他场景。另外一些成语虽然也是字面意思，但是对仗工整，朗朗上口，比如众叛亲离、心直口快等

对仗工整不大懂，所以不知道工不工整。疲劳驾驶不琅琅上口？不琅琅上口的话怎么那么常用？

@ChingLiu 常用的词多了，不大可能，路上小心，解题思路。p.s. 我查了一下朗朗上口和琅琅上口，两个都正确，但是琅琅上口的应用场合更多。

成语 need to have some kind of reference. Generally, 成语 comes from historical events, myths, legends or stories from classical works.
For example: 如火如荼，杯弓蛇影，愚公移山，風聲鶴唳
So it's quite difficult to form new 成语

"So it's quite difficult to form new 成语" Yes, though the sub-cultural impact of the Internet to form "new" 成语 should not be underestimated in pushing new and fast growing developments of the Chinese language, (indeed any language) because the future belongs to the mass of literate young, unlike in the distant past where only a small and exclusive number of literati had any form of influence on the language. Given enough time and common usage, many loose sayings now would become 成语  in its own right. Take 鼠头鸭脖 for example. It sounds like a counter reply to 挂羊头卖狗肉 and so deserves recognition.

很多成语也没有故事啊：心直口快，下不为例。感觉成语不一定是metaphor

I agree with Kymo's idea and Fat Penguin's idea.
疲劳驾驶并不算成语，因为它并没有什么深刻的含义，它只有自己的“字面意思”。我是说它的背后没有任何典故，也不包含任何道理。成语通常出自一些典籍或寓言故事(fictions)，有些成语是对一个事件的概括。
成语 is not something like "verb", "adjective" or "noun" in English, 它一个宽泛的概念，我们无法完全确定地说一个词语是不是成语。(thus, 成语字典上面没办法收录所有的成语，你只能在上面查到常见的那些)对于成语的字数，它们大多数都是4个字的，但是我也不确定有没有其他字数的。(虽然我是中国人，但毕竟我不是专门研究中文的专家）。
据我所知，应该没有21世纪新产生的成语。我觉得主要原因是很多成语是“约定俗成”产生的, so it requires a long time to produce a new 成语.

In one sentence, 约定俗成 means 事物的名称或法则,经人相约遵用,久而久之,为社会所公认或实用. If  you cannot understand that, perhaps you can use Google to search for more information in English


例行公事，下不为例的深刻意义是？

几乎每个疲劳驾驶 都是一个个悲剧。想想看疲劳驾驶用在哪里？外卖小哥，滴滴司机，卡车司机身上。没有压力的话，需要驾驶到疲劳？没有悲剧发生，会需要用到疲劳驾驶？不够深刻？

Although 疲勞駕駛 consists of four characters, it does not satisfy the two essential criteria for idiomaticity:
(1) 疲憊駕駛 and 勞累駕駛 are perfectly fine collocations, but they do not count as idioms, either. If you can freely substitute close synonyms ot related words, you are probably not dealing with an idiom.
(2) As long as one knows that 疲勞 means "tired" and 駕駛 means "drive", the meaning of 疲勞駕駛 is perfectly clear: "driving while tired". When it comes to idioms, however, even if you know what the individual words mean, the overall meaning is still unclear or opaque (context can of course furnish clues).

IDIOM CRITERIA (only 1 and 2 are essential)
(1) Fixedness: The words can NOT be replaced with synonyms or similar words. Most idioms also have a fixed word sequence: 高談闊論 NOT 闊論高談, 鷄毛蒜皮 NOT 蒜皮鷄毛 (although geese and ducks have similar feathers, the idiom cannot be rephrased as 鵝毛蒜皮 or 鴨毛蒜皮).
(2) Figurative Meaning: The surface meaning of 鷄毛蒜皮 is chicken feathers and garlic skin, but it really means "trivial unimportant matters.
(3) Four Characters: Because of Chinese structure, most idioms do indeed consist of four characters, but there are hundreds of four character phrases 四字格 that are neither fixed not figurative: 不可不知、三番兩次、沒頭沒腦. Taken alone, the fact that an expression consists of four characters does not automatically mean it is an idiom. A small number of idioms consist of three, five or more characters: 不分青紅皂白
(4) Literary Allusion 典故: Not all idioms can be traced to some work of literature, ancient or modern, but some dictionary or textbook writers dredge up one single isolated occurrence in a obscure poem or essay (the more ancient the better) as "proof" that this is an idiom, even if there is no record of continuous use over the intervening centuries. The fact that an obscure four character phrase (made of rare words) has traceable roots should not be used as proof that this is an idiom.

Example A: 乳臭未乾 rǔ xiù wèi gān / ruu shiow wey gan || lit. "the smell of mother's milk has not dried off yet" || "[derogatory expression] too young and inexperienced" || (1,2) If rephrased as 奶味兒還沒有乾 the phrase assumes a literal meaning: you are talking about the actual smell of milk.
Example B: 害群之馬 hài qún zhī mǎ / hay chyun jy maa || lit. "the horse that harms the herd" || "A person who harms the group by being selfish, not following the rules etc" || (1) The idiom 害群之馬 cannot be rephrased as 損害馬群的一匹馬 (2) Just like a "bad apple" is not a piece of fruit, 害群之馬 refers to bad guys, not horses

As a language is in constant changes with the social development, of course there are new idioms of Chinese like 不明觉厉 十动然拒 鼠头鸭脖 提灯定损 何弃疗 意难平 前方高能 厚礼蟹 阿伟死了 双厨狂喜 蓝瘦香菇 恐龙扛狼 恶意返乡 动态清零 that are the products of Internet cultures.

鼠头鸭脖，动态清零 我知道。意难平 我能理解。恐龙扛狼，后礼蟹 不算吧！它们应该就是别音吧。不然河蟹也是成语了

@ChingLiu What you said is senseless. You are not a judge or a decision maker. History is not determined by you or with your acceptance. Do you know that 目不识丁 is an idiom because it is a misspelled phrase?
